# CSS stylesheet not added on localhost, bootstrap, XAMPP

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, xampp

when i open http://localhost/Website/home.html my css stylesheet is not showing up. Maybe it is something with the bootstrap css? I am new to both bootstrap and XML. Here is my home.html head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>****</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

My style.css is located in the same folder as my home.html

**EDIT**: some of my css are now showing, but not all. Strange..

**EDIT 2**: Apparently the bootstrap CSS did something fishy, it works if i changed the order to this:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: It's more likely that either Bootstrap's CSS overrides yours, your stylesheet has a syntax error, or the rules are wrong. You need to show the contents of your CSS file and the HTML for the elements where it doesn't work.

Comment: Because some of your css does show, there might be an error in your css. Can you please provide your code, so we can help you finding your error.

Comment: It was the Bootstrap CSS that was the problem, by adding <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> at the bottom it was solved :D